# Potential at Center of Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential, potential-energy

If using the surface of the earth as a reference point how much work is needed for gravity to pull me to the center. Is it negative infinity or am I wrong? Also is a single value of potential meaningless. Does it represent anything? Do you at least need a potential difference for it to represent work done? I'm extremely confused about potential and potential energy.

Answer (score 1):

> $R$:Radius of Earth.
>   $x$:distance from centre.
>   $M_e:$Mass of Earth.
>   $m$:mass of object.

**Answers:**

**How much work is needed for gravity to pull me to the center?**

Force inside or on surface of earth

> $$\large F = \frac {GM_emx}{R^3}$$

Work done by Earth

> $$W=  \int_R^0 F.dx = \int_R^0\frac {GM_emx}{R^3}.dx
>  = -\frac {GM_em}{2R} $$
>
> ---

**Is it negative infinity or am I wrong?**

No it isn't.

---

**Why not force= GMm/x^2? –  @DWin**

**Edit/Force on object:** The Earth can be considered as composed of several shells of infinitesimal width and at an interior point the force due to shells with radius greater than the distance of that point is zero. Thus effective mass of earth is:

> $$M^{'}=\frac {M_e}{\frac 43 \pi R_e^3} . \frac 43 \pi x^3 = M_e . \frac {x^3}{R^3}$$
>   $$F^{'}=\frac {GM_em}{x^2} . \frac {x^3}{R^3} = \frac {GM_emx}{R^3}$$

---

**Alternatively** from analogy of a charged solid sphere the Electric field inside the sphere from Gauss' Law is:

> $$E=\frac{KQx}{R^3}=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Qx}{R^3}$$

So force on a point charge q is :

> $$F=\frac{KQqx}{R^3}$$

By analogy of $G\equiv K,Q\equiv M_e,q\equiv m$ ,the above result can be verified, proved or understood.

---

**Edit/Potential and Potential Energy:**

> Also is a single value of potential meaningless. Does it represent anything? Do you at least need a potential difference for it to represent work done?

There is no meaning of absolute potential, potential of a point is generally the potential difference wrt $\infty$ as

> $$V_{p,\infty}=V_p-V_{\infty}$$

And usually we take $V_{\infty}=0$, So the potential of a point is actually $\Delta V_{p,\infty}$.

Comment: Why not force= GMm/x^2?

Comment: @DWin see my edit

Comment: Putting both R and x in the equation is just confusing the matter. You haven't actually defined what R is supposed to represent and if it's not the same as x, then it's just wrong.

Comment: @Dwin do you know understand.

Comment: I understand, but if if you think that R^3 where R is the radius of the Earth in the denominator is correct for the force at height x, then _you_ are the one who doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The change in energy is the integral of $gM(h)~dh$ where $M(h)$ (the mass of Earth below the height) is decreasing as a function of height, h,  above the center. It is only the mass of the earth that is "below" the object that is moving that exrts a radial force. The portion that is at a greater distance from the Earth's center no longer exerts a force. (Newton proved this in his *Principia*). I would have said that You were turning potential energy at the surface and at each into kinetic energy as the object (or you) fell to the center. If instead there were friction slowing the object or it were being lowered then the potential energy would be turned into either heat or mechanical energy.

$$F = Gm(\frac{4}{3} \pi~\rho(x) ~x^3)/x^2$$ where $\rho$(x) is the variation in the effective density below a radius of $x$. The expression:  {4}{3} \pi~\rho(x) ~x^3 , yields the mass in the sphere out to radius $x$ while the division by $x^2$ is just the inverse radius-squared relation from the gravitational equation. The citation by *_* is interesting because it shows that there is very little change in F as a function of x for changes in x near the Earth's surface because of the increased density of the core relative to the crust.

The potential at the center could be any number but most conveniently would be taken as zero. The $M$ will vary as $x^3/R^3$ and as the link offered by @Aditya points out, there is the further complication that the density of the rock varies with the radius as well, so the force will not exactly vary as $1/r$.

Comment: "that exerts a radial force", should be "any force". No force can be felt by a test mass within a spherical shell http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/sphshell2.html

Comment: I could have said any "net force". I still think there is "force" from different parts of the outer "shell" but the various contributions balance to zero. I suspect that this would also hold true for an elongated ellipsoid, probably by some argument using Green's theorem, but have not seen that problem actually solved.

Comment: OK, "net force" is saying the same thing as any. The calculation assumes gravitational forces coming from various parts of the spherical  shell and cancelling.

Comment: Yes. Spherical. It's not necessarily as simple with other sorts of symmetry.

Comment: also what you say, g should also be a function of height

Comment: No. `g` is a constant. What varies is the mass within the sphere whose radius is your distance from the center.

Comment: @Dwin No. g is also dependent on distance see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Depth)

Comment: @Dwin Don't answer a question if you have incomplete knowledge. Field inside earth is not proportional to $1/x^2$ but $x$ see also g is not a constant.

Comment: You are confusing variations in rho (the mass density of the rock at various radii) with variations in g. I say again _g_is_a_constant_.

Comment: @DWin I am sorry but it is G that does not change, the one that enters in the general formual G*M*m/r**2 . small g changes with altitude http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Altitude  also http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/9/4/894a6547e0e7448dc9035ea56ee19b24.png

Comment: When that citation is talking about 'altitude', it is distance above the Earth's surface. That is not a consideration in this problem.